# Pivot on two columns with both numeric and categorical value in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, pivot

I have a data set in pyspark like this :
from collections import namedtuple

```
    user_row = namedtuple('user_row', 'id time category value'.split())
    data = [
        user_row(1,1,'speed','50'),
        user_row(1,1,'speed','60'),
        user_row(1,2,'door', 'open'),
        user_row(1,2,'door','open'),
        user_row(1,2,'door','close'),
        user_row(1,2,'speed','75'),
        user_row(2,10,'speed','30'), 
        user_row(2,11,'door', 'open'),
        user_row(2,12,'door','open'),
        user_row(2,13,'speed','50'),
        user_row(2,13,'speed','40')
    ]
    
    user_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    user_df.show()
+---+----+--------+-----+
| id|time|category|value|
+---+----+--------+-----+
|  1|   1|   speed|   50|
|  1|   1|   speed|   60|
|  1|   2|    door| open|
|  1|   2|    door| open|
|  1|   2|    door|close|
|  1|   2|   speed|   75|
|  2|  10|   speed|   30|
|  2|  11|    door| open|
|  2|  12|    door| open|
|  2|  13|   speed|   50|
|  2|  13|   speed|   40|
+---+----+--------+-----+
```

What I want to get is something like below where grouping by id and time and pivot on category and if it is numeric return the average and if it is categorical it returns the mode.

```
+---+----+--------+-----+
| id|time|    door|speed|
+---+----+--------+-----+
|  1|   1|    null|   55|
|  1|   2|    open|   75|
|  2|  10|    null|   30|
|  2|  11|    open| null|
|  2|  12|    open| null|
|  2|  13|    null|   45|
+---+----+--------+-----+
```

I tried this but for categorical value it returns null (I am not worry about nulls in speed column)

```
    df = user_df\
    .groupBy('id','time')\
    .pivot('category')\
    .agg(avg('value'))\
    .orderBy(['id', 'time'])\
    
    df.show()

+---+----+----+-----+
| id|time|door|speed|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  1|   1|null| 55.0|
|  1|   2|null| 75.0|
|  2|  10|null| 30.0|
|  2|  11|null| null|
|  2|  12|null| null|
|  2|  13|null| 45.0|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Which door you want to select for id 1 and time 2 open/close?

Comment: I have the whole logic for filling the null after I could pivot the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an additional pivot and coalesce them. try this.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from collections import namedtuple

user_row = namedtuple('user_row', 'id time category value'.split())
data = [
    user_row(1,1,'speed','50'),
    user_row(1,1,'speed','60'),
    user_row(1,2,'door', 'open'),
    user_row(1,2,'door','open'),
    user_row(1,2,'door','close'),
    user_row(1,2,'speed','75'),
    user_row(2,10,'speed','30'), 
    user_row(2,11,'door', 'open'),
    user_row(2,12,'door','open'),
    user_row(2,13,'speed','50'),
    user_row(2,13,'speed','40')
]

user_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
#%%
#user_df.show()
df = user_df.groupBy('id','time')\
            .pivot('category')\
            .agg(F.avg('value').alias('avg'),F.max('value').alias('max'))\
#%%
expr1= [x for x in df.columns if '_avg' in x]
expr2= [x for x in df.columns if 'max' in x]
expr=zip(expr1,expr2)
#%%
sel_expr= [F.coalesce(x[0],x[1]).alias(x[0].split('_')[0]) for x in expr]
#%%
    
df_final = df.select('id','time',*sel_expr).orderBy('id','time')

df_final.show()
+---+----+----+-----+
| id|time|door|speed|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  1|   1|null| 55.0|
|  1|   2|open| 75.0|
|  2|  10|null| 30.0|
|  2|  11|open| null|
|  2|  12|open| null|
|  2|  13|null| 45.0|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: actually this is not what I need, I need something to be exactly as my second table in the question

Comment: @Maddie - check out the edited answer. this gives the exact output as expected

Comment: I edit my post (see my expected table - second table). So I guess we need to somehow pivot it but not sure how?!

Comment: @Maddie - check out now

Comment: what does sel_expr= [F.coalesce(x[0],x[1]).alias(x[0].split('_')[0]) for x in expr] do?

Comment: Coalesce returns the first non null value. In our case average of the string 'open' will give null. In that case we have to take the max value

Answer (score 1):

Try collecting the data and transforming as required

> spark 2.4+

```
user_df.groupby('id','time').pivot('category').agg(collect_list('value')).\
        select('id','time',col('door')[0].alias('door'),expr('''aggregate(speed, cast(0.0 as double), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc/size(speed))''').alias('speed')).show()

+---+----+----+-----+
| id|time|door|speed|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  1|   1|null| 55.0|
|  2|  13|null| 45.0|
|  2|  11|open| null|
|  2|  12|open| null|
|  2|  10|null| 30.0|
|  1|   2|open| 75.0|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: thanks, however my version of Spark is 2.2 so this does not work